# How to align the table header to stick with the first row of the table in ITEXT

Tags: itext, itext7

I am generating a PDF which is like

Page1:

ABC: 
Sample Content Table

ABC1:
Sample Content Table

ABC2:

---

Page 2:
The table for ABC2 starts here....

I would like to bring the header (ABC2) down to next table and ensure it always sticks on with the table content.

I can achieve this bu using table.setKeepTogether(). he header wraps to next page if grid starts from next page. But the problem i am facing here is that this induces lot of white spaces in the PDF document.

Example:

Page 1 has below content:

Table 1 Header:
The table

Table 2 Header:
The table

---

Page 2:

Table 3 Header:
a small Table

### Then a full block of white space as the Table 4 does not fit into Page 2

### (I don't want this to happen, i want the Table 4 to start in the Page 2 (jus below the Table 3) and then split the table upon reaching end of Page 2)

Page 3:

Table 4 Header
Table

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want the ABC2-table to start on the next page?

Comment: Yes, If ABC2's table starts in second page, I would like to bring the table header ABC2 also to page 2.

Comment: So you have a header element (it's not a `Table`s header, but a `Paragraph` or `Div` or sone other `BlockElement`) and you want it to be processed with the table, so that if the table goes to the next page, that header goes to the next page as well. Am i right?

Comment: I am currently using !SplitLate && SplitRows which gives me the expected output except the factor that the page have space to hold table header alone is in the previous page and the grid below is completely in the second page - it displays the header at end of previous page and grid starts in the next page. I want the header in this case to wrap to next page and stick on with grid.

Comment: `splitLate` is a method from iText5, not from iText7. So which solution do you want: iText5-based or iText7-based?

Comment: I can achieve this (Header sticking with grid) if i add setKeepTogether(true) - but then it nulls the previous condition (!SplitLate && SplitRows )

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk : I have updated my question to give you better clarity

Comment: @UladzimirAsipchuk : Please let me know if its still baffling...

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce it (perhaps I still don't understand what your problem is).

Comment: What is your "header"? Is it a different table? Why don't you use table's header element (#addHeaderCell in iText7)?
Could you add your code, so that one can observe it?

Comment: Also: do you use iText5 or iText7? (they are both mentioned in the questions tag section.